# How to calculate the number of months between two dates in a datastage

Tags: etl, datastage

I need to calculate the number of months between two dates, I used to do it in Teradata using months_between function, but currently I need to the similar function or code to use in datastage.

I have tried below code but it's not matching 100% with the results given months_between function.

I have subtracted two dates, got number of days from it and divided it by 30.4375.

Comment: So explain what is a month for you - i.e. is 3.1. to 1.3. two months or one?  Give some examples of what you expect...

Comment: we are rounding off the value, like 3.1 is 3 and 3.6 as 4

Comment: use substring on the date to get your month and then do a difference operator to get it.

Comment: if we use substring then year will be neglected, we don't want that

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do the maths by yourself in a DataStage function or a Transformer.
Following functions can be helpful

- MonthFromDate
- YearFromDate